# Adding a Content Security Policy vs above the fold css

Tags: css, security, content-security-policy, policy

I am implementing a **content security policy** onto my website. I currently have on-page css for *above the fold* content to 'please' Google insights and create a faster loading website for the end user. Google also recommends on-page css for *above the fold* content so that is what I have done.

As the **Content Security Policy** disables css, it means that the page wont display properly if I add it so Im unsure what to do. It seems I have 2 choices.

1. Forget about adding a Security Content Policy altogether and keeping things as they are.

Or

2. Add a Security Content Policy and put ALL css to an external file but that then creates 'Render Blocking Content' messages in Google Page insights which could impact user click-through-rate and possible SEO.

Surley theres another way???

Thanks for all your advice in advance.
Ezzo

Comment: You have a third choice - keep CSP and add `'unsafe-inline'` or `'nonce-value'` to the `style-src` directive.

Comment: I can fix this using nonce but im confused in that the tutorials are saying that the nonce is a 'one time number' and needs to be randomly generated. I added the following to the website whereby the nonce value is something I just made up. On html page i changed <style> to <style nonce="abc12345"> and then added in Nginx add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; style-src 'nonce-abc1234'; "; and this worked and Mozilla Observatory liked it, but now any hacker can view my source code to see my nonce value. I was going to use this nonce (abc1234) for multiple pages on my website

Comment: Yeah, it's much secure to generate a new `nonce` on each request. You can do it even for [add_header in Nginx](https://csplite.com/csp250/). Alternatively you can use `'sha256-value'` (`'hash-value'`) token instead of `'nonce'` - you need to regenerate it only if you change the `<style></style>` content.

Answer (score -1):

CSP is a very powerful tool to protect your website, and it would be a shame not to leverage it.
Using `unsafe-inline` for the `script-src` directive is indeed very unsafe.
However, `unsafe-inline` for the `style-src` directive is considered OK, given that it cannot be used for XSS.

I don't know which website vulnerability checker you are using (human / tool), but you can look at an [CSP scan of github.com](https://cspscanner.com/?q=github.com), and see that they also have `style-src: 'unsafe-inline'`, and still score an A- on the grader (best-in-class by far).

Use the scanner to make sure you are constructing the CSP correctly, and not leaving our crucial elements like the `base-uri`, `object-src`, etc.

I can help further if you post the website / CSP that you have now.

Comment: Hi, I can fix this using nonce but im confused in that all the tutorials are saying that the nonce is a 'one time number' and needs to be randomly generated. I added the following to the website whereby the nonce value is something I myself just made up.

Comment: @ezzo if you use a hard-coded nonce, it defeats the purpose of this mechanism.
The idea is that the nonce is not accessible or known to the attacker. If they found an injection to your site, and know the nonce, they would just inject it with the XSS payload: `<script nonce="HARD_CODED_NONCE">alert("XSS pwned")</script>`
That is why the nonce needs to be dynamic and unpredictable - so the attacher cannot inject it.

Comment: I notice that CSPScanner.com is your own product. Please don't [spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) us. You _must_ disclose any relationship you have to products or services you promote. This is not the right place to build brand awareness.